# Hiding Column In a Datagridview which's data source is a binding source

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I am using a datagridview in my form, which's data source is a binding source control. In the current changed event of the binding source control I am trying to hide the rows in the datagridview. Then I get the following error,

> Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made invisible.

The code i used is given below,

```
rowClicked = reportsBindingSource.Position
for (int i = 0; i < dgvItems.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (rowClicked != i)
                        {

                            dgvItems.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }

                }
```

What is wrong with the code? I tried using the below but nothing works,

```
CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dgvItems.DataSource];
                   currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
                   dgvItems.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                   currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
```

and

```
dgvItems.CurrentCell= null
dgvItems.Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: As indicated in the exception, hiding rows in data bound mode is not supported. What exactly is the use case?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev    I wanted to hide all the rows except the selected one in the current changed event of the binding source

Comment: Hmm, so you want to always show in the grid only the current item from the binding list? Sorry for the questions, but sounds strange to use a grid for showing a single record.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev    we ate adding some more functionalities to an existing software, And in the old software the datagrid is used everywhere, so can't change it at this moment since the forms are inheriting from the parent form. Now we really want to hide all other rows except  the selected row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as indicated by the exception, hiding rows is not supported in data bound mode. So in order to achieve your goal, you should use some data binding mechanism.

From data binding perspective, "hiding" rows is equivalent of filtering the source list. Since the `BindingSource` component can act as both single item and list data source, the easiest is to use intermediate `BindingSource` containing the `Current` of the primary source, like this:

```
BindingSource bindingSource; // Your current component used as DataSource for the dataGridView

var currentSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = bindingSource.Current };
dataGridView.DataSource = currentSource;
bindingSource.CurrentChanged += (_sender, _e) => currentSource.DataSource = bindingSource.Current;
```

Comment: This will solve the issue particularly in my case, but as you said loading a datagridview with just one item is not that a much appreciable. I am thinking of other solutions